# get link with imap connection

Tags: php, email, imap

I connect to my gmail account via this code

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
        $username = 'myacount@gmail.com';
        $password = 'password';

        /* try to connect */
        $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

        /* grab emails */
        $emails = imap_search($inbox,'all');

        /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
        if($emails) {

          /* begin output var */
          $output = '';

          /* put the newest emails on top */
          rsort($emails);

          /* for every email... */
          foreach($emails as $email_number) {

            /* get information specific to this email */
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
            $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
            $message=strip_tags($message);
            /* output the email header information */
            $emai=split("<",$overview[0]->from );
            echo 'Lus ou pas : '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'lue' : 'Non Lue').'<br>';
            echo 'subject : '.$overview[0]->subject.'<br> ';
            //echo 'from : '.$overview[0]->from.'<br>';
            echo 'from : '.$emai[0].' + '.$emai[1].'<br>';
            echo 'date :  '.$overview[0]->date.'<br>';

            /* output the email body */
            echo 'Message '.rawurlencode(utf8_decode(rawurldecode($message))).'<br>';
            break;
          }

          echo "<br><br><br><hr><br><br>";

        }

        /* close the connection */
        imap_close($inbox);
```

in my account I have one email   her body have

```
http://www.test.com?id=4
```

but when I execute my script I have her in my browser

```
Lus ou pas : Non Lue
subject : test
from : =?ISO-8859-1?Q?fai=E7al_name?= + myacount@hotmail.com>
date : Mon, 24 Sep 2012 13:39:11 +0000
Message %0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%3D0A%3D%0D%0A%3D0A%3D%0D%0A%3D0A%3D%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%3Fid%3D3D4%20%09%09%20%09%20%20%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%20%09%20%20%20%3D%0D%0A%09%09%20%20%0D%0A%3D%0D%0A
```

how can I get the link exactly.

Ps : English Is not my mother tongue, sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: it looks like you message gets urlencoded somehow

Comment: yes you have right bat i d'ont now how i can fix that
when I change it   echo 'Message '.$message.'<br>'; i have this  Message =0A= =0A= =0A= http://www.test.com?id=3D4 = =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo 'Message : '.quoted_printable_decode($message).'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$s = urldecode('%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%3D0A%3D%0D%0A%3D0A%3D%0D%0A%3D0A%3D%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%3Fid%3D3D4%20%09%09%20%09%20%20%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%20%09%20%20%20%3D%0D%0A%09%09%20%20%0D%0A%3D%0D%0A');
echo $s;
```

It will output `=0A= =0A= =0A= http://www.test.com?id=3D4 = =` to the screen.

If have no idea why your message is urlencoded in the first place. But it works in you email client, because the email client will urldecode the message to.

Comment: I did that echo 'Message '.urldecode(rawurlencode(utf8_decode(rawurldecode($message)))).'<br>';
chi give me that Message =0A= =0A= =0A= http://www.test.com?id=3D4 = =

Comment: Why not put the plain message in the email body?

Comment: ok i send this message in my gmail acount "hi how are you im fine" when I execute my script I have her in my browser "Message hi how are you im fine = = "

Comment: Looks fine to me. `Message` is the message start, and `= = " -` is the mime separator